# how to send $(this).atta('id') using cake php js helper

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

HIi Folks i am having one issue please help me i want to send some data to my controller using ajax call i have written all code but for data field

```
<?php echo $this->Js->get('.menu')->event('click',$this->Js->request(array('controller' => 'restaurants', 'action' => 'getItem'),array('async' => true,'method'=>'POST','update' => '#HFNames','data'=>'$(this).attr(id)')),false); ?>
```

when ajax call hits it take "$(this).attr(id)" as a params but i need the value of cureent click

js helper genrate this
if we remove that double quote from this genrated script then its working 
  data: "$(this).attr(id)",
why this get quoted

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".menu").bind("click", function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        data: "$(this).attr(id)",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            $("#HFNames").html(data);
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "\/foodkingkong\/restaurants\/getItem"
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What you want generated would be something like this:

    `data: { "id" : $(this).attr("id") },` How to do it in that horrible syntax is up to you to figure out.

Comment: yes if we can generate this then i hope it will work help me how we can generate this

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.

```
 echo $this->Js->buffer('$(".menu").bind("click", function (event) {
         $.ajax({
                 async: true,
                 data: $(this).attr(id),
                 dataType: "html",
                 success: function (data, textStatus) {
                         $("#HFNames").html(data);
                 },
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "/foodkingkong/restaurants/getItem"
         });
         return false;
 });'
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Himanshu we had planned to do the same directly using jquery but wanted to do the same via cakephp bind function only.
What will be the difference if we pass the js in buffer.